# blocked UI in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i am trying to build an application, following MVVM strategy. unfortunately my primitive example (please see below) is blocking the UI, although i specifically called for dispatcher. not sure why.. any suggestions?

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;

    private string _name;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    }

    public string Name
    {

        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void InvokePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
        PropertyChangedEventHandler changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed != null)
            changed(this, e);
    }

    public void send()
    {
        Action dispAc = () => NameAsync();
        _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(dispAc);
    }

    private void NameAsync()
    {
        Name = "name1";
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

ps.
the first reply clarified a problem, thanks. for those of you, who does not use 4.5, i use

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(dispatchAction);
```

rest is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` for this task. `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` bring you current executing thread which likely is the UI thread. That means, `NameAsync()` function is invoked in the UI thread, and of course still block the UI. You can use [Task.Run()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to execute your method asynchronously to avoid blocking UI :

```
Action dispAc = () => NameAsync();
Task.Run(dispAc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're dispatching the work on... the UI thread.  Do your work on a different thread, then, when you're done, dispatch the UI updates onto the UI thread.

Except you don't even have to.

As long as you're not on 3.0 of the framework, bindings will automatically marshal INPC `PropertyChanged` events onto the UI thread.  So you can dispense with any dispatching when touching these properties from a worker thread.

Using your example...

```
public void send()
{
    // We're on the UI thread here
    Task.Run(() => NameAsync());
}

private void NameAsync()
{
    // we're on some anonymous threadpool thread right now
    Name = "name1";
    // the event is fired on the threadpool, but bindings automatically marshall
    // UI update code onto the UI thread, so it returns directly before UI is 
    // changed
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    // and now our threadpool thread is sleeping.  Good night, sweet prince.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this,

```
public void send()
{
    Action dispAc = () => NameAsync();
    _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(dispAc);
}
```

to this

```
public void send()
{
 Action dispAc = () => NameAsync();
  _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(dispAc, DispatcherPriority.Background);
}
```

If you don't really need the `UI thread` to execute a method that requires the `Dispatcher` then just use `TPL`.

By default if you did not specify the `DispatcherPriority` it will use the `Normal` so it will use whatever the current thread is which is possible to hog the `UI Thread` e.g., while it tries to do some `Render` for other controls.

By the way, if you are using `.NET 4.5` might just consider using the `await` and `async` keyword. If not, then like others suggest just spawn a different thread to update the `UI`. `WPF`'s `Dispatcher` is smart enough to marshall the `UI` update to the main thread compared to `Silverlight` or `WinRT`.